# Как написать запрос, чтобы посчитать процент от суммы записей группы?

Tags: sql, таблицы

Есть две таблицы со столбцами:

```
users(id, country_id)
orders(id, user_id, amount_usd)
```

Нужно написать запрос, который бы выводил: `country_id`, `user_id` и долю от дохода, полученную со страны регистрации пользователя (`country_id`):

Пример вывода:

```
country_id user_id percent
RU           12      6.33
BY           112     1.11
RU           632     2.51
UA           231     4.65
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот этот запрос соответствует задаче

```
    SELECT
    u.id,
    ROUND((o.amount_usd /SUM(o.amount_usd) OVER (PARTITION BY u.country_id))* 100,2) AS percent
    FROM users u
    JOIN orders o
    ON o.user_id = user_id
    GROUP BY
    u.id, u.country_id;
```